# Editing and saving xml using a form

Tags: php, xml

I'm building a php application which uses a one-page form to select an item from the xml document, bring up some of its elements in editable fields and then save over them.

Currently I have the dropdown list which properly lists all of the restaurants in the xml file:

```
<?php
$restaurantreview = simplexml_load_file('restauraunt_reviews.xml');
   
$restaurant = $restaurantreview->Restaurant;
    
echo "<select Name='r_select' id='r_select' onchange='this.form.submit();'>"
            . "<option value='' >Select ...</option>";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($restaurant); $i++) {          
    echo "<option value='".$i."'>" . $restaurant[$i]->Name . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Once the user selects a restaurant a set of fields is supposed to come up, but when they do the fields are all empty. I'm worried that I might not be calling the value of r_select properly.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST["r_select"])){?>
    <br>Address: <br>
    <input type = "text" name = "Street" value = <?php $restaurant[$r_select]->Address->Street?>>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<?php } ?>
```

Am I misunderstanding how to pass the value of the selected option from the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I think I understand what people meant by passing the value at this point:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST["r_select"])){
            $r_select = $_POST["r_select"];
            $s_r = $restaurant[intval($r_select)];
            ?>
        <div class="container form-group">
            <label for="Street" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Street Address:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Street" value = "<?php echo $s_r->Address->Street?>"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Call and declare r_select in the next area, then when you're referencing its location in the XML you need to use intval to ensure its interpreted as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is on the server and the dropdown is in the browser.

In the first code snippet, I see that you read in the XML and then compile a SELECT that is embedded in the HTML. This HTML is sent to the browser.

You wrote that the dropdown is displayed correctly.
What then?
Then the user selects a restaurant and then?
How does the server know what detail data to display?
How does the selected restaurant get back to the server?

Idea: The user must click Submit and the ID of the restaurant is sent to the server, e.g. via POST. Then the server searches for this restaurant in the XML and writes its address into the address field, into the HTML. This HTML with the address then comes back to the user.

Comment: The way I understand it, all I really need from the select statement is the value of the index location. I want it so that the fields with the information will automatically fill based on the selection, the only submit button should be for when those fields are filled & edited and then submitted for saving. Maybe I should change the onchange part? As it stands I don't think r_select ever becomes a value I can pass later for referencing.

Comment: Debug your $_POST["r_select"]. How will the value from $_POST come to $r_select? Validate the $_POST["r_select"] and if valide, so transfer its value to $r_select. Then debug $restaurant[$r_select]  - if that is the relevant object.